# Javascript: how overwrite/rename the keys of an object?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this object

```js
[{
    "id": 2,
    "email": "admin@example.com",
    "role_id": 1,
    "is_active": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-10-10T17:05:34.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-10T17:05:34.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "email": "agency_owner@example.com",
    "role_id": 2,
    "is_active": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-10-11T18:30:06.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-11T18:33:51.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
}]
```

I would get another object:

```js
[{
    "value": 2,
    "text": "admin@example.com",
}, {
    "value": 3,
    "text": "agency_owner@example.com",
}, {
    "value": 4,
    "text": "license_owner@example.com",
}]
```

So, renaming "id" with "value" and "email" with "text".

I would use `map` and maybe not installing lodash or similar...

Thank you...

Comment: Then use `map`: `modified = original.map(obj => ({value: obj.id, text: obj.email}));`

Answer (score 0):

Well, `map` is a great idea. What is stopping you from using it?

You can:

```js
obj = [{
    "id": 2,
    "email": "admin@example.com",
    "role_id": 1,
    "is_active": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-10-10T17:05:34.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-10T17:05:34.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "email": "agency_owner@example.com",
    "role_id": 2,
    "is_active": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-10-11T18:30:06.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-11T18:33:51.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
}]

obj = obj.map(e => { return {
  value: e.id,
  text: e.email
}})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` as you mentioned:

```
var arr = [{
    "id": 2,
    "email": "admin@example.com",
    "role_id": 1,
    "is_active": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-10-10T17:05:34.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-10T17:05:34.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "email": "agency_owner@example.com",
    "role_id": 2,
    "is_active": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-10-11T18:30:06.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-11T18:33:51.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
}];

var result = arr.map(o => {
    return { value: o.id, email: o.email}
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "email": "admin@example.com",
    "role_id": 1,
    "is_active": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-10-10T17:05:34.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-10T17:05:34.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "email": "agency_owner@example.com",
    "role_id": 2,
    "is_active": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-10-11T18:30:06.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-11T18:33:51.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
}].map(function(obj){
return {
value:obj.id,
text:obj.email
}
})
```